# spring boot - spring data jpa error

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa

main class annotations -

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan( basePackages = "com.webstar" )
@EntityScan(basePackages = "com.webstar.models" )
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.webstar.repository") 
@EnableAutoConfiguration

public interface UserAccounts extends JpaRepository<Registration, Long>
{

}
```

my test class -

```
@RunWith( SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class )
@WebAppConfiguration
public class RegistrationTest
{
    @Autowired
    private UserAccounts userRepo;

    @Test
    public void testRegistration()
    {
        Registration reg = new Registration("1212","1212","1212","121","1212",null,null);



        userRepo.save(reg);

    }
}
```

Error - Caused by the following:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type

My repository and models are in different packages.

Comment: Does it mean that `UserAccounts` declare `@SpringBootApplication` and `JpaRepository` at the same time? If not, you should improve your post.

Comment: No..first is springBootMainClass annotations only - 2nd is repository class which extends to JpaRepository and third one is test class where i am trying to autowire UserAccounts.. Not sure why i cant autowire UserAccounts from test class.

Comment: You might need a @ContextConfiguration annotation in RegistrationTest.

Comment: Last time I had this problem my test was missing the following:
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = Application.class, webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.NONE)
Application.class: change this to match your App Config. 
Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

Let's say that you have the following configuration:

Your entity package `com.other.model`

Your repository package: `com.other.repository`

Your testing class that is in a totally different package: `foo.test.mydemo.MyOtherAppTest`

Go to `foo.test.mydemo.MyOtherAppTest` class and add the following annotation:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@SpringBootConfiguration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EntityScan(basePackages = "com.other.model")
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.other.repository")
public class MyOtherAppTest {
```

Answer (score 0):

on you RegistrationTest.class
add  annotation: 
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(class=classname.class)
//classname is you main class name
if you use springBootTest
use @SpringBootTest(class=classname.class)
//classname is you main class name
wish help you ~